# How to get Index names and Index fragmentation list for each databases?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get each tables' in the all databases' index fragmantation details. I wrote a procedure but it gives me only system databases' indexes.

I've created 3 tables; one for index names, one for index fragmantations and third one for joined tables. I don't have a problem with joined table.

And my code looks like that:

```
create table #IndexDetails
(
id int identity(1,1),
[DBName] nvarchar (max) NULL,
[tablename] nvarchar(max) NULL,
[avg_fragmentation_in_percent] float NULL,
[index_type_desc] nvarchar (max) NULL,
)


create table #IndexName
(
id int identity(1,1),
IndexName  nvarchar(max) NULL,
TableName  nvarchar(max) NULL,
ColumnOrder nvarchar(max) NULL,
IsIncluded nvarchar(max) NULL,
ColumnName nvarchar(max) NULL
)
 

insert into #Indexname
select 
    i.name as IndexName, 
    o.name as TableName, 
    ic.key_ordinal as ColumnOrder,
    ic.is_included_column as IsIncluded, 
    co.[name] as ColumnName
from msdb.sys.indexes i 
join msdb.sys.objects o on i.object_id = o.object_id
join msdb.sys.index_columns ic on ic.object_id = i.object_id 
    and ic.index_id = i.index_id
join msdb.sys.columns co on co.object_id = i.object_id 
    and co.column_id = ic.column_id
where i.[type] = 2 
and i.is_unique = 0 
and i.is_primary_key = 0
and o.[type] = 'U'
--and ic.is_included_column = 0
order by o.[name], i.[name], ic.is_included_column, ic.key_ordinal


Exec sp_MSforeachdb 'USE msdb'; 
insert into #IndexDetails
select msdb.sys.databases.name AS DBName, 
msdb.sys.tables.name As tablename, 
msdb.sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent, 
msdb.sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats.index_type_desc
from msdb.sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(N'?'), Null, Null, Null, 'SAMPLED')
JOIN msdb.sys.tables ON msdb.sys.tables.object_id=msdb.sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats.object_id
JOIN msdb.sys.databases ON msdb.sys.databases.database_id=msdb.sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats.database_id
where avg_fragmentation_in_percent >=30 
and msdb.sys.databases.name not in ('msdb','master','model','tempdb')
and msdb.sys.databases.state_desc ='ONLINE'
```

Can you help me with this problem?

Regards,
(I'm working on Microsoft SQL Server 2017)

Comment: What happens when you query databases that are not `msdb`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Index fragmantation part gives me database's details where I executed in.
Index names part does not return any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your execution of `sp_MSforeachdb` will only switch context for the dynamic sql executing within that call. It won't switch the context for all of the following code. Also, your current code says `sp_msforeachdb 'use msdb'`. It needs to be `sp_msforeach 'use [?]'`. The `[?]` will be automatically populated with each db name inside the execution of `sp_msforeachdb`

Here is an example of using it correctly:

```
exec sp_msforeachdb 'use [?]; select db_name()'
```

Not:

```
exec sp_msforeachdb 'use [?]'
select db_name()
```

Also, you will not be able to refer to the #temp tables created in your outer scope, because the dynamic sql executing inside sp_msforeachdb can't see them. You can use global temp tables if you wish (`create table ##mytable`)